'Row Label' appears as first column header as well as subtotals appear, while generating excel pivot table using apache poi
I am generating an excel with pivot table using apache poi. Pivot gets generated. However, there are two issues observed
Source table:



Employee ID
Employee Name
Location
Salary




100
John
London
5000


101
Chris
New York
6000


102
Mary
Los Angeles
10000


103
Lilly
London
6000


104
Joe
Toronto
3000


105
Dan
New York
7500



Issue:
Generated excel pivot shown here 
Issue Description:

The first column header of the pivot observed to be as 'Row Label', instead of the actual pivoted column header (here 'Employee ID'). How to ensure the actual pivoted column header ('Employee ID') appears as first column header
Subtotals appear for each row. How to disable subtotal using apache poi?

Here is my code
public class ExcelPivot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XmlException {

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("employee_template.xlsx");
                Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {
            List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
                    new Employee("100", "John", "London", 5000.00),
                    new Employee("101", "Chris", "New York", 6000.00),
                    new Employee("102", "Mary", "Los Angeles", 10000.00),
                    new Employee("103", "Lilly", "London", 6000.00),
                    new Employee("104", "Joe", "Toronto", 3000.00),
                    new Employee("105", "Dan", "New York", 7500.00)
            );

            fis.close();
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Employee");

            for (int r = 1; r <= employeeList.size(); r++) {
                Employee obj = employeeList.get(r - 1);
                Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
                Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
                cell1.setCellValue(obj.getEmployeeId());
                Cell cell2 = row.createCell(1);
                cell2.setCellValue(obj.getEmployeeName());
                Cell cell3 = row.createCell(2);
                cell3.setCellValue(obj.getLocation());
                Cell cell4 = row.createCell(3);
                cell4.setCellValue(obj.getSalary());
            }

            XSSFSheet pivotSheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheet("Summary");

            AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:D7", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
            CellReference position = new CellReference("B10");

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, position, sheet);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
            pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3, "Sum Of Salary");

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setColGrandTotals(false);

            for (CTPivotField ctPivotField : pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields()
                    .getPivotFieldList()) {
                ctPivotField.setOutline(false);
                ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption("");
            }

            System.out.println("Pivot Generated");

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("employee_template.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            wb.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static class Employee {
        private String employeeId;
        private String employeeName;
        private String location;
        private double salary;

        public Employee(String employeeId, String employeeName, String location, double salary) {
            super();
            this.employeeId = employeeId;
            this.employeeName = employeeName;
            this.location = location;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public String getEmployeeId() {
            return employeeId;
        }

        public String getEmployeeName() {
            return employeeName;
        }

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

    }

}

I couldn't find any documentation in Apache poi with respect to this. Also, tried various property settings such as
For Issue 1 (Row label issue) I tried this:
//pivotSheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).setCellValue("Fund Id"); 
For Issue 2 (Subtotal issue) I tried this:
ctPivotField.setSumSubtotal(false); ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false); ctPivotField.setVarSubtotal(false);
But, nothing seems to be affecting/changing the generated pivot table. Does any of you have any suggestions to fix this issue?

Figured out the fix for the Issue #1
Basically,  we need to set the below explicitly
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("E,mployee ID");
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setColHeaderCaption("Location");

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411982/pivot-unclear-grouping-remove-result-rows/76416606#76416606

For the first "problem" you might want using the  "Classic PivotTable Layout". Thus

Set Grid Drop Zones true to show the drop zones for pivot fields.
Set Compact and Compact Data to false so the whole layout is not a
compact layout.

See Need to enable 'Classic Pivot Table Layout' option in excel using Apache POI JAVA:
Code:
...
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCompact(false);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCompactData(false);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setGridDropZones(true);
//pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setMultipleFieldFilters(false);
//pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setItemPrintTitles(true);
for (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotField pivotField : pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList()) {
 pivotField.setCompact(false);  
 pivotField.setOutline(false);  
}
..

For the subtotal problem see Pivot unclear grouping / remove result rows. Using my static void addRowLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, Sheet dataSheet, AreaReference areaReference, int column,  boolean defaultSubtotals) in your code instead of XSSFPivotTable.addRowLabel like so:
...
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(source, position, sheet);
//pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
//pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
addRowLabel(pivotTable, sheet, source, 0, false);
addRowLabel(pivotTable, sheet, source, 1, false);

pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
        
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3, "Sum Of Salary");
...

results in following:

Note: This needs the full jar of all of the schemas poi-ooxml-full-XXX.jar (previously known as ooxml-schemas)  according to FAQ-N10025.

Thanks @Axel Ritcher for the quick response. I tried adding the above suggested code for RowLabel . But, i get the error - 'The type org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTString cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files'
for the line - 'pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(column)
.getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);'

@Keerthi K: This needs the full jar of all of the schemas poi-ooxml-full-XXX.jar (previously known as ooxml-schemas)  according to FAQ-N10025.

Thank you so much. I was able to resolve this issue :)
